# Maki icons not all displaying

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to build a map which allows users to choose icons for their geojson points. I just want to use the default map styles (streets|outdoors|light|dark|satellite) and Maki icons, however, not all icons are showing on all styles.

For example 'bicycle' and 'cafe' show on all the map styles, 'circle' only shows on satellite, and 'marker' doesn't show on any of them.

On a style I developed for another purpose, all markers show fine even though I know I didn't do anything special to 'add' them to the style.

So, my code is not the problem, my question is about the availability of maki icons on the default styles. I would have thought they'd all be available on all styles, but it seems not.

How can I tell which icons will work across all the default styles (short of trial and error)?
Is there some way I can 'enable' all the icons on a style?

Failing that, if I do have to make my own versions of the basic styles, I guess I can, but how do I ensure all the icons are loaded into the style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Mapbox styles are fairly optimised, and don't include anything that's not needed to display them. So, icons that aren't used in the style itself aren't included.

When you create a new style, I think Mapbox by default includes the whole Maki set.

If you can modify the style file (JSON) directly, you could try changing this line (for the Mapbox Streets style):

```
"sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/streets-v9",
```

to the equivalent in one of your custom styles, something like:

```
sprite": "mapbox://sprites/woowoowoo/htd32t6hd236t",
```

But it might cause problems if there are icons in Mapbox Streets that aren't in your style.

In short, I don't think there's a simple way to add "all the icons". Each style has its own set of icons.

A better way might be to use `addImage`/`loadImage` to load the custom icons you want, at run time. See [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/).

Comment: Thanks Steve, I sort of expected as much in terms of the styles only having a subset of icons. It looks like there are some icons that are available in all styles. I guess I just have to build a little test bed to leverage that.
Custom icons are another branch of what I'm planning - not quite there yet :-)