# Display maki icons on markers according to geojson feature property

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

in the past, I created my maps on the Mapbox website and embedded them on my Jekyll blog using an iframe. Now, I [developed a jekyll plugin](https://github.com/rriemann/jekyll-maps/tree/mapbox-geojson) that consumes a geojson file and employs Mapbox GL JS to display maps.

I would like to support [Maki icons](https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/) for indvidual marker using GeoJSON feature properties using the [SimpleStyle Spec](https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec/tree/master/1.1.0)

How can reproduce the following map with features including marker symbols defined in GeoJSON?

[image]

Current Mapbox code for Jekyll Maps: [on Github](https://github.com/rriemann/jekyll-maps/blob/61ec29d2bade388bc9b2e01ef5d742754ac01399/lib/jekyll-maps/mapbox_api.js#L54)

Related question:

- for Mapbox.js (Leaflet): [Mapbox - Custom marker icons from GeoJson properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234428/mapbox-custom-marker-icons-from-geojson-properties)
- for Mapbox GL JS: [Maki icons not all displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567773/maki-icons-not-all-displaying)

Comment: What current problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I want to define markers for display in the geojson file. I wonder how I can load either all maki icons or those in a subset when using Mapbox GL JS. There are only tutorials for one custom icons, not for multiple custom icons so far.